# Duplicate rows in BigQuery using Pub/Sub subscription

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing a `python` script that generates `N` distinct messages that I am publishing to a topic on `Google Cloud Pub/Sub` using `BatchSettings(max_messages=1_000, max_bytes=1_000_000, max_latency=1)`.
Each message has a unique identifier, either a `uuid.uuid4` or an `integer` from an increasing sequence.

The aforementioned topic has a BigQuery Pub/Sub subscription that writes messages to a table with a given `Pub/Sub schema`.

When start pushing messages at a rate of `800000` per `20s` (`40000/s`). I observe duplicate rows in the BQ table. Even at a rate of `10000/s`, duplication is observed.

The BQ Pub/Sub subscription has the following settings:

```
Use topic schema : Enabled
Write metadata : Disabled
Drop unknown fields : Disabled
Subscription expiration : Subscription will never expire.
Acknowledgement deadline : 600 seconds
Subscription message retention duration : 7 days
Retain acknowledged messages : No
Exactly once delivery : Disabled (cannot be enabled)
Message ordering: Disabled
Dead lettering: Disabled
Retry policy : Retry after exponential backoff delay
Minimum backoff duration : 60 seconds
Maximum backoff duration : 600 seconds
```

Is this to be expected? What can I do in order to avoid ending up with duplicate rows?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think this shouldn't occur, but did you check the code that pushes to pub/sub to confirm if there isn't any way for it to duplicate the message? I had a similar problem when handling some exception

Comment: Fair point, I indeed have a try except block. I will definitely dig into that ! I will get back to you regarding this.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos, removing the try except block did not lead to change in behavior. Thanks for the lead though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some level of duplication is expected as Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery semantics, including for BigQuery subscriptions. Typically, we expect the duplicate rate to be around 0.1%.

The first question with regard to duplicates is, are they generated on the publish side or are the on the subscribe side (when writing from Pub/Sub to BigQuery)? To answer this question, enable the `write_metadata` property on your subscription. Then, look at the uniqueness of the `message_id`s relative to the uniqueness of the identifier you are putting in the messages. If you have multiple messages with different `message_id`s, but the same identifier you put in the message, then the duplicates are coming on the publish side. If you have messages with the same `message_id`, then the duplicates are coming on the subscribe side and fit within the expectation of the at-least-once delivery guarantees provided by Pub/Sub.

If the duplicates are generated on the publish side, then it's possible your publish load is overloading the client in some way and resulting in a lot of deadline exceeded errors, which causes reattempts at publishing. You could consider taking advantage of [publisher flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#flow_control). By setting `PublishFlowControl.message_limit`, you can restrict the number of messages awaiting a publish response at a time, which limits the resources needed for publishing and makes it less likely that you will run up against resource constraints that could lead to increased rates of errors and duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the long and thorough answer. I will investigate and get back to you regarding the above-mentioned potential issues.

Comment: After playing around with what you have suggested I was able to solve the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamal - are there any guarantees of non-duplication on the subscribe side? Given it's managed by GCP. Can't easily find this in the docs.

Comment: No, there are no guarantees of duplication on the subscribe side. You can use the [exactly once feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) to provide stronger guarantees around delivery.